# How to install (missing dependencies for) QMPlay2 video player in 18.04 (Kubuntu)?

Tags: video, dependencies, 18.04

Using Kubuntu I am interested in Qt programs, like the video player QMPlay2.

Deb files are available [here](https://github.com/zaps166/QMPlay2/releases) for various Ubuntu releases, including 18.04.

I have seen in some youtube tutorials that installation in 16.04 from the specific deb involved some missing dependencies solved with `sudo apt-get -f install` ([here](https://youtu.be/q6ZgBWgMDgs)), while the installation in 17.04 from deb for that version involved no such problems ([here](https://youtu.be/7pGa9Vpai3E)).

Trying to install the deb for 18.04:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/qmplay2-ubuntu-amd64-18.04.01-1.deb
Selecting previously unselected package qmplay2.                         
(Reading database ... 193267 files and directories currently installed.) 
Preparing to unpack .../qmplay2-ubuntu-amd64-18.04.01-1.deb ...          
Unpacking qmplay2 (18.04.01-1) ...                                       
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qmplay2:              
 qmplay2 depends on libcdio13; however:                                  
  Package libcdio13 is not installed.                                    
 qmplay2 depends on libva1; however:                                     
  Package libva1 is not installed.                                       
 qmplay2 depends on libva-x11-1; however:                                
  Package libva-x11-1 is not installed.                                  
 qmplay2 depends on libva-glx1; however:                                 
  Package libva-glx1 is not installed.                                   
 qmplay2 depends on libva-drm1; however:
  Package libva-drm1 is not installed.
 qmplay2 depends on libpcre16-3; however:
  Package libpcre16-3 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package qmplay2 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Running `sudo apt-get -f install` at this point removes the installed but unusable `qmplay2` package:

```
 sudo apt-get -f installReading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  qmplay2
```

Is it possible to install the missing dependencies?

(For example, `libcdio13`  is not available here, while it was available in 16.04 - as indicates here:
[How to install libcdio13 on Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus)](https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/main/libcdio13/)
.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm your problem, I wrote [comment on GitHub tracker](https://github.com/zaps166/QMPlay2/issues/175#issuecomment-388755694) of the project

Update: bug [was fixed upstream](https://github.com/zaps166/QMPlay2/issues/175#issuecomment-388968919), so the installation process is simple:

```
wget https://github.com/zaps166/QMPlay2/releases/download/18.04.01/qmplay2-ubuntu-amd64-18.04.01-2.deb
sudo apt install ./qmplay2-ubuntu-amd64-18.04.01-2.deb
```

---

Section below is for historic purposes.

We have two options here:

## * Download dependencies from 17.10 and install them manually

1. We download dependencies from 17.10 and install them by the following commands:

   ```
   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libc/libcdio/libcdio13_0.83-4.2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
   sudo apt install ./libcdio13_0.83-4.2ubuntu1_amd64.deb

   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/libv/libva/libva1_1.8.3-2_amd64.deb
   sudo apt install ./libva1_1.8.3-2_amd64.deb

   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/libv/libva/libva-x11-1_1.8.3-2_amd64.deb
   sudo apt install ./libva-x11-1_1.8.3-2_amd64.deb

   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/libv/libva/libva-glx1_1.8.3-2_amd64.deb
   sudo apt install ./libva-glx1_1.8.3-2_amd64.deb

   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/libv/libva/libva-drm1_1.8.3-2_amd64.deb
   sudo apt install ./libva-drm1_1.8.3-2_amd64.deb
   ```
2. Then we download latest deb-packaged version of QMPlay2 and install it

   ```
   wget https://github.com/zaps166/QMPlay2/releases/download/18.04.01/qmplay2-ubuntu-amd64-18.04.01-1.deb
   sudo apt install ./qmplay2-ubuntu-amd64-18.04.01-1.deb
   ```
3. Then start it with `QMPlay2` command or from GUI.

## * Compile source package and use it

While waiting the reaction from developer, you can compile the package manually:

```
wget https://github.com/zaps166/QMPlay2/releases/download/18.04.01/QMPlay2-src-18.04.01.tar.xz
tar -xf QMPlay2-src-18.04.01.tar.xz
cd QMPlay2-src-18.04.01/
mkdir build
cd build

sudo apt-get install cmake pkg-config qtbase5-dev libva-dev \
libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libass-dev libasound2-dev \
libtag1-dev qttools5-dev checkinstall
```

Then it will configure with the following options:

```
$ cmake ..
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:342 (message):
  Missing QtSvg module - SVG icons will not be visible!


-- Enabled features:
 * Freedesktop notifications, Use Freedesktop notifications
 * Datmusic, Build with Datmusic support
 * AnimeOdcinki, Build with AnimeOdcinki support
 * Wbijam, Build with Wbijam (anime) support
 * LastFM, Build with LastFM support
 * Tekstowo, Build with Tekstowo lyrics support
 * libass, Build with libass support
 * Inputs, Build with Inputs module
 * Modplug, Build with Modplug module
 * Extensions, Build with Extensions module
 * MPRIS2, Build Extensions with MPRIS2 support
 * Visualizations, Build with Visualizations module
 * AudioFilters, Build with AudioFilters module
 * VideoFilters, Build with VideoFilters module
 * OpenGL2, Build with OpenGL2 module
 * TagLib, Build with tags editor
 * FFmpeg, Build with FFmpeg module
 * ALSA, Build with ALSA module
 * CUVID, Build with CUVID module
 * Notifications, Build additional notifications module

-- Disabled features:
 * libavresample, Use libavresample instead of libswresample
 * PortAudio, Build with PortAudio module
 * VAAPI, Build VAAPI acceleration into FFmpeg
 * VDPAU, Build VDPAU acceleration into FFmpeg
 * libavdevice, Build FFmpeg with libavdevice suport
 * AudioCD, Build with AudioCD module
 * Chiptune GME, Build Chiptune with GME support
 * Chiptune SIDPLAY, Build Chiptune with SIDPLAY support
 * PulseAudio, Build with PulseAudio module
 * XVideo, Build with XVideo module
 * Git version, Append Git HEAD to QMPlay2 version
 * Link Time Optimization, Enable link time optimization for release builds
 * Address Sanitizer, Use Address Sanitizer
 * Undefined Behavior Sanitizer, Use Undefined Behavior Sanitizer
 * SolidActions, Install Solid actions

-- Build type: Release
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to:
```

Start compiling with:

```
$ make -j8
```

You can launch the player with:

```
$ src/gui/QMPlay2
```

Comment: @cipricus As you may see bug is fixed upstream.